# How to make the assigned values not getting changed after modifying the list used to assign

Tags: c#, list

I have a list like this

```
List<Employees> elist = new List<Exployees>();
```

This has n number of records
and I um declaring another fresh list and used following approaches

```
List<LateEmployees> lateList = new List<Employees>(elist);
```

and after that I m adjusting values in elist . After that I have seen the values in the lateList also got changed.

Then I used this approach

```
foreach(var entity in elist){
   lateList.Add(entity)
}
```

After changing the elist property values the same has happened all over again .

How do I prevent lateList getting changed after modifying the elist in C# 4.5

Comment: Can you specify "changing the elist value"? You mean set properties of individual employees?

Comment: Yes for example adjust the In-time of the previous list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although lateList is a separate list, the items it contains are still the same employee objects. As such any change to those objects will happen in both lists. In other words, the only difference between the lists is *which* employees they contain, not the specifics of the employees.

In order to save the old versions of the employees to lateList you will need to copy each employee to a new Employee object - copying all the property values - and then add the *copies* to lateList.

e.g:

```
foreach (var entity in elist)
{
    lateList.Add(new Employee()
    {
        InTime = entity.InTime
        //Other properties too
    });
}
```

It is advisable to put the "new Employee() { }" stuff in a method (e.g. "Clone()" of Employee so you can reuse it later.

Comment: I have many properties in that Employee class  isnt there a better way in C#  to do it ?

Comment: I've never used it myself but you can try this method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Be advised that in both implementations you will need to take care to also create copies of any properties that are themselves reference types.

Comment: Why the things are so hard in C#?